# acf Image Crop Editor Not working

Tags: wordpress, image, editor, crop

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKdpx.png)

I am having an issue in wordpress admin where the images are not cropping in WP "edit image" for a site I am creating and I do not know what the cause is.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? We noticed an issue with crops when we had PHP 5.5 running.

Comment: php 5.6   xampp 5.6 on os

Comment: Have you tried disabling all plugins and using the default theme? That's usually a best-practice in debugging (WP_Debug on would help too).

Comment: Yes i tried disabling all the plugins, still not working even i changed directory permissions to 777. WP_Debug is also turned on. When i edit image, it returns -1 with the following link, not the image preview.
 wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=imgedit-preview&_ajax_nonce=bcf9ce9aa2&postid=150&rand=91018